# Getting "No SCHEMA dataset name was specified" while running FME script

Tags: gis, shapefile, fme

While running the FME script I am encountering the following error message :

No SCHEMA dataset name was specified (couldn't find a value for `SCHEMA_2_DATASET' or` SCHEMA_DATASET')

I have upgraded to the new FME version 2021.2 from the old FME version (2016).

The script is running fine on the old(2016) FME version but having some issues in the new FME(2021.2) version.

The script has multiple shape file parameters
[Parameters used in script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7xlk.png)

The data set in the FME script code are in the following format :

```
#! <DATASET

#! NAME="SCHEMA_1"

#! OVERRIDE="-SCHEMA_1_DATASET"

#! DATASET="abc.shp"

#! />

#! <DATASET

#! NAME="SHAPE_1"

#! OVERRIDE="-SHAPE_1_DATASET"

#! DATASET="def.shp"

#! />

#! <DATASET

#! NAME="SCHEMA_2"

#! OVERRIDE="-SCHEMA_2_DATASET"

#! DATASET="ghi.shp"

#! />

#! <DATASET

#! NAME="SHAPE_2"

#! OVERRIDE="-SHAPE_2_DATASET"

#! DATASET="jkl.shp"

#! />

#! <DATASET

#! NAME="SCHEMA_3"

#! OVERRIDE="-SCHEMA_3_DATASET"

#! DATASET="mno.shp"

#! />
```

I am adding values of Project Name, Outline SHP, Parcel SHP #1 and Attribute Name #1.

The remaining values are NULL.
Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

I am expecting to get this script executed without any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above issue got resolved for me by doing following steps:

1. Go to the Navigator Pane in FME workbench.
2. Go the translation parameters option.
3. Set **Rejected Feature** to 'Continue Translation'
4. Set **Ignore Failed Readers** option to "Yes"